# Does JDBC have different behavior on java EE comparing to Java SE?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish, java-ee-7

So I'm learning Java and I made couple projects in Java FX, Swing and MySql.

I never had any problems with database. Today I wanted to try to make application in java EE with MySql, and as soon as I started Glassfish I got this error `"no suitable driver found for jdbc"` even though i have added jar file.

So I did little research and read that MySql connector should be put in server lib\ext folder, this is the path `C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext`.

After that I got a different error `"Cannot open file:C:\glassfish5"`, so I googled the error and solution was to put `useSSL = false` in the JDBC url, so now it looks like this `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"`.

After this I was able to connect with MySql and read the data. But now I'm totally confused because I don't understand the reason for copying jar file in the server folder and what is this `useSSL` in my link?

Why is the process for connecting different for Java EE?  Is this a standard for every Java EE project or I did something wrong?

Comment: Fair question. Java EE implements "middleware". This means it takes care for you of a lot of technical details, you used to do manually. However, at the same time it forces you to follow the rules of the framework.

Comment: Are you trying to use `DriverManager`? It is not recommend to use that in a JavaEE environment, instead configure a `DataSource`. But if you are using `DriverManager`, the likely cause is that you didn't load the driver using `Class.forName`. Automatic driverloading only works for drivers on the initial classpath, which is probably not the case here.